# Points on the surface $x y^3 z^2=16$ that are closest to origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I have to find the points on the surface

$$E = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : xy^3z^2=16\}$$
that are closest to the origin. How should we approach to this problem?

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's multiplier?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: You could look for points on the surface at which the gradient is parallel to the position vector, but using the AM-GM inequality, as Jack D'Aurizio does [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2721818/265466), is simplest.

Answer (score 4):

Actually for finding 
$$ \max_{xy^3 z^2=16}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$
you do not need Lagrange multiplies, nor derivatives. By the AM-GM inequality $$ 256 = x^2 y^6 z^4 = 108\cdot x^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}y^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}y^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}y^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}z^2 \cdot\frac{1}{2}z^2 \leq 108\left(\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{6}\right)^6$$
hence $xy^3 z^2=16$ implies 
$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \geq \sqrt[12]{\frac{256}{108}\cdot 6^6} = \color{red}{2\cdot 3^{1/4}} $$
with equality attained at the points such that $x^2=\frac{y^2}{3}=\frac{z^2}{2}$. Here it is a nice sketch of the situation:

$\hspace1in$[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to get use to this website and I will be more careful when I ask questions.